# control speed of 12v dc fan with thermistor

Tags: dc, bjt, 12v, fan, thermistor

As a learning exercise, I am trying to control a 12VDC/0.18A computer fan with a thermistor.  As I am planning the circuit (and I certainly can be wrong in my calculations), I plan to have a 12V power source (8AA batteries in series).  I am trying to use a PN2222 transistor to control the fan's speed.  According to my calculations, I would need 6mA into the base of the transistor to get the 180mA needed to run the fan at (or close to) full speed.  So, then to control the speed from there, i.e. clamp down the current going to the base to reduce the current into the fan, I have placed a 5-100K thermistor in line with a 2K resistor.

Connections:  Negative rail connected to Emitter and 2K Resistor which also connects through thermistor to base.  Collector is connected to negative side of fan.  Positive rail connects to positive terminal of fan.
[image]

I believe I have included all the pertinent information, but if I left something out, I'll be happy to add more.

So, the problem I am having is that the fan doesn't even turn.  I have connected the fan directly to the battery source, and the fan turns.  I have started some basic troubleshooting, but found that I am reading 0V across the 2KR (1.9K pictured).  So, I guess my question is what am I missing here?  Why can I not get the fan to turn in this circuit, and I am sure it is probably something stupid.

Comment: A picture (or in this case a circuit diagram) is better than a 1000 words. BTW you haven't actually asked your question.

Comment: We need a circuit diagram to see how you've connected this. You're probably going to want to have your transistor as an emitter follower and be thinking voltage control rather than current limiting as you seem to be as that is dependent on the (highly variable) gain of the transistor. Also, a 2n2222 is going to get quite hot, you might want something beefier in a TO220 package.

Comment: I have added a circuit diagram about my idea.  I also added some additional information of what I have tried so far to troubleshoot.  As for the transistor, I believe it is a TO-92 package, according to the datasheet that I have for it.  Also, this is not going to be running long-term.  I don't know how quickly the transistor will heat up, but I am only trying to get this running to prove the concept.  This is not for a real-world application...just learning.

Comment: I might have missed something in your question, but the transistor base needs to be positive with respect to the emitter to turn on.  The transistor base is currently connected to the emitter.  As a heuristic solution, you can use a potentiometer to see at what point the fan will turn on, then size your resistor and thermistor accordingly.

Comment: @PICyPICyPICy, so as I said in my question, it is probably something stupid.  That being said, I should move the connection from the 1.9KR from the negative rail to the positive rail?

Comment: This could start a long discussion, but a transistor is generally considered to "turn on" at a base voltage of 0.7V.  It is probably best to connect the base to one of your 1.5V batteries with an appropriate base resistor.  If you're not familiar with this then it may be best to do a little reading and spend some time with a simulator like LTSpice.

Comment: @PICyPICyPICy Changing the connection from negative to positive on the resistor worked!  The fan is turning now.  I am not seeing an appreciable change in the fan speed based on temp, but at least I am closer to an answer.  Thanks for the help and pointing out the connection error on the base.  (Told you it was probably something stupid.)

Comment: @Jonathan this solution you've choosen will be a _very_ inefficient one. Is that something you're okay with? Considering you're going to use batteries to power it up.

Comment: Hi @HarrySvensson, as mentioned before, this is a learning experiment....just trying to see what I can do with what I have.  It is not for anything more than entertainment/learning.  Since it is a learning session, I am happy to hear suggestions on how to make it better.

Comment: @PICyPICyPICy, if you could put your solution regarding the transistor base being positive with respect to the emitter as an answer, I will select it as such, since that was the thing that made the project work.  I have since tested it by placing the DMM in line with the fan to get the amp reading.  By varying the temperature of the thermistor (ice pack, fingers) I can see and hear the difference in the speed of the motor.  Is there a way, without a microcontroller to make a change in resistance be more drastic?  A 5R-100KR range is pretty large and requires a lot of heat to see difference.

Comment: As you can understand, the transistor in your schematic is never 100% open or 100% closed, it's in between. That means that it has much voltage and much current flowing through it. \$P=U×I\$. To make it more efficient you have to close it so \$I=0 Ampere » P=0\$, and then switch the transistor so it's 100% open so \$U=0 Volt » P=0\$. If you do this switching fast enough, say 40kHz, then you won't hear the switching and it will be very efficient (somewhere around 80-99%). In your case the efficiency is between 5-99%, depending on how open or closed the transistor is. Google switching regulator.

Comment: @Jonathan Making a base terminal positive with respect to emitter will turn on the transistor. So that current flow happens from collector to emitter. But you have to control base current in order to change the collector. Collector current changes in exponential way to the base emitter voltage. Very minute increase in base emitter voltage.

Comment: @Jonathan You can control the speed using PWM from a 555 timer.  No need to shy away from micro controllers with the Arduino platform.

Comment: @PICyPICyPICy Unfortunately, 555 timers have a max PWM duty cycle of 50%! If you need higher than 50%, you'll have to invert the signal and the logic behind increasing/decreasing fan speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have missed something in your question, but the transistor base needs to be positive with respect to the emitter to turn on. The transistor base is currently connected to the emitter. As a heuristic solution, you can use a potentiometer to see at what point the fan will turn on, then size your resistor and thermistor accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am thinking you want something like this, using a mosfet it can handle more current and using the "pot" makes it temperature variable.

Comment: 1: MOSFET vs BJT has nothing to do with current handling capability.  // 2: Why not use a real schematic?  // 3: Could you tell us a little about the "characteristics" of this circuit?  The transistor has a Vgs threshold voltage and non-linear transconductance.  Oh and the NTC is also non-linear.  A curve of (temperature, current~RPM) would be nice. // 4: How come there is a copyright notice in the image?

Comment: I copied straight from the source .... http://www.heatsink-guide.com/  and have built several like this .